# How to record audio and play it with WatchOS2?

Tags: objective-c, watchkit

In watchOS 2, Apple has included a new feature to allow apps to record short audio files but, how can I call this new method in my existing WatchKit project?

```
- (void)presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:(NSURL * nonnull)URL
                                              preset:(WKAudioRecordingPreset)preset
                                     maximumDuration:(NSTimeInterval)maximumDuration
                                         actionTitle:(NSString * nullable)actionTitle
                                          completion:(void (^ nonnull)(BOOL didSave,
                                                               NSError * nullable error))completion;
```

My problem is not how to called that method, is that Xcode compiler says that this function is not found. Do I have to include any additional Framework? Could it be because my WatchKit project was create with a previous version of WatchOS?

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, but my question was about the new WatchOS version. Someone answer after I asked.

Comment: @EntriMR Duplicates merely create networks between questions. Answers on both questions are relevant, so it doesn't matter when each question was asked.

Answer (score 2):

**1) You need to create a file URL at which to store the recorded output.**

```
NSArray *filePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                         NSUserDomainMask,YES);
NSString *path = [[filePaths firstObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"rec.m4a"];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

You may specify the extensions .wav, .mp4, and .m4a.

**2) Call the method as follows:**

```
[self presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL:fileUrl
                                            preset:WKAudioRecordingPresetWideBandSpeech
                                   maximumDuration:5.0
                                       actionTitle:@"Some Title"
                                        completion:^(BOOL didSave, NSError * __nullable error) {

                                            NSLog(@"didSave:%d, error:%@", didSave, error);
                                        }];
```

You can choose preset in addition to the above

- WKAudioRecordingPresetNarrowBandSpeech
- WKAudioRecordingPresetHighQualityAudio

**In Swift:**

```
self.presentAudioRecordingControllerWithOutputURL(
    self.recFileURL(),
    preset: WKAudioRecordingPreset.WideBandSpeech,
    maximumDuration: 5.0,
    actionTitle: "SomeTitle") { (didSave, error) -> Void in

        print("didSave:\(didSave), error:\(error)")
}
```

You can play the recorded file as follows:

```
self.presentMediaPlayerControllerWithURL(
    fileURL,
    options: nil) { (didPlayToEnd, endTime, error) -> Void in

        print("didPlayToEnd:\(didPlayToEnd), endTime:\(endTime), error:\(error)")
}
```

You can check the detail specification [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/watchos/documentation/WatchKit/Reference/WKInterfaceController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014957-CH1-SW93).

Comment: I received an error when I write that method to be called. Should I include some library? My project was created with the previous version of WatchOS

Comment: @shu223...can u explain How to Record and Play audio using objective-c for Watch